# How do I use a VBA input box to call a sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I have twelve reports, one for each month.  Depending on the month entered, I would like to run the corresponding macro that compiles the report (also labeled by the months of the year).  Is there a way to use the input box to call a macro?

Comment: See this question's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406523/excel-vba-call-function-with-variable-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when the `InputBox` prompts the user to input a month, store the user's input into a variable. In your macro that has the  `InputBox`, after the cell is populated with the user's choice, you can use an if statement to call another function/macro.

```
Dim month as String
Dim var as Variant
month = InputBox("Enter the month", "Month Report", 0)

var = array("January","February","March", ...)

For Each c in var
    If month = c Then
        Application.Run c & "()"
        Exit sub
    End if
Next c

End Sub
```

Make the macro names the same as the entries of the month, so if a user inputs "January" it will run the macro January().

Comment: Thanks.  Can you elaborate on the array or list?

Comment: It is an shorter way than using 12 if statements. Look at edit

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, you save the input box input as a string, then compare it to whatever criteria you need. This comparison can be done with either a giant If then statement block or a Select Case block.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MonthTest()
Dim strMonth As String

strMonth = InputBox("enter month here")

If strMonth = "January" Then
    Call January
    MsgBox "You put in January"
ElseIf strMonth = "February" Then

End If
End Sub

Option Explicit

Sub CallMonthCase()

Dim strMonth As String

Select Case strMonth
    Case Is = "January"
        Call January
    Case Is = "February"
        Call February
    'etc etc
End Select
End Sub
```

Case structures worth a little faster, and look  much cleaner, but are typically harder to craft syntactically as we humans don't think way

Comment: Thanks.  Can you elaborate on the Select Case block?