# Pass Sub as a parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub

```
Sub MySub1

MsgBox "I am ok!"

End Sub
```

Then I have a so called "method sub" with parameters

```
Sub MySub2 (Parameter1, Parameter2, MethodName)

MsgBox Parameter1
MsgBox Parameter2

MethodName

End Sub
```

Then I would like to run this whole chain in my master. I have tried the following:

```
Sub MasterSub

Dim Parameter1 As String
Dim Parameter2 As String
Dim MethodName As String

Parameter1 = "Ou"
Parameter2 = "Yes"
MethodName = MySub1

MySub2 Parameter1, Parameter2, MethodName

Dim
```

This is giving an error that value or function is expected. How to make this work?

Comment: [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run).

Comment: Is there some reason you want it to be a parameter? You can accomplish something similar by passing it a string as the name of a subroutine (method) and then use a `Select Case` or `If` to run a certain subroutine based on the value of the string...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406523/excel-vba-call-function-with-variable-name

Comment: @BigBen `Application.Run "MethodName"` works. I haven't tried second suggestion, but I will check it as well

Comment: @braX This seems to be the one I was thinking to try out. So instead of using Sub convert it to Function. By the way is there any difference in performance etc between these two?

Comment: `Sub` doesn't return a value. `Function` does. That's why when you say `MethodName = MySub1`, this will not assign any value to `MethodName`. I suspect that's why you are getting the error. If you convert it to a function, do forget to assign a return value to the function (i.e. before the end of `MySub1` sub, have something like: `MySub1 = "This is a test"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `Module` (as you can see on screenshot below):

[image]

Then paste this code:

```vb
    Private Sub MySub1()
        MsgBox "I am ok!"
    End Sub

    Private Sub MySub2(Parameter1, Parameter2, MethodName)
        MsgBox Parameter1
        MsgBox Parameter2

        Application.Run MethodName
    End Sub

    Sub MasterSub()
        Dim Parameter1 As String
        Dim Parameter2 As String
        Dim MethodName As String

        Parameter1 = "Ou"
        Parameter2 = "Yes"
        MethodName = "MySub1"

        MySub2 Parameter1, Parameter2, MethodName
    End Sub
```

And then click on `Run Sub/User Form` button (or click on `F5` key) for run your macro.